# Visual Basic Loops Even When Condition Isn't Met

Tags: vb.net, while-loop

I'm trying to program a motorized stage in an xy array configuration in visual basic. I take the n x n array size as input from the user and I move the stages accordingly. Here I am testing a value of 3 so a 3x3 array, The problem occurs with the outer y loop. When County reaches a value of 4, larger than the 3, the loop iterates again, adding another row to my array. Why is it iterating again even though the loop condition isn't satisfied?

Countx and County are my counters and increment every time the stage is moved. Switch is to alternate between the x stage moving back and forth (in a snake pattern)

```
    Dim countx As Integer = 1
    Dim county As Integer = 1

    Dim switch As Integer = 1

    While county <= arraysize

        If switch = 1 Then
            While countx < arraysize
                AxMG17Motor1.MoveJog(0, 1)
                countx = countx + 1
                Await Task.Delay(5000)
            End While
            switch = -1
            county += 1
            AxMG17Motor2.MoveJog(0, 1)
            Await Task.Delay(5000)

        End If

        If switch = -1 Then
            While countx > 1
                AxMG17Motor1.MoveJog(0, 2)
                countx = countx - 1
                Await Task.Delay(5000)
            End While
            switch = 1
            county += 1
            AxMG17Motor2.MoveJog(0, 1)
            Await Task.Delay(5000)

        End If

    End While
```

Comment: If you `Dim a(3) As Integer` then `a.Length = 4`, in case that resembles how the code is working with `arraysize`.

Comment: Also you're adding to county in both blocks, so by the time it gets to the end of the while, county would be 5. Step through in the debugger or add something like this to see it change: `Debug.Print(String.Format("county {0} countx {1} switch {2} arraysize {3}", county, countx, switch, arraysize))`

Comment: @AndrewMortimer ahh that makes sense I see what I was doing wrong now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer absolute moves if possible. You can iterate over the indices and create locations.

I believe you can also be more accurate in allowing the motors to both complete their moves, rather than a "blind" 5 second wait. I am not sure about the thread safety of AxMG17MotorLib moving multiple stages asynchronously, but it's worth a try.

```vb
Dim rows = 3
Dim cols = 3
Dim jogSizeX = 5
Dim jogSizeY = 10
Dim originX As Single
Dim originY As Single
AxMG17Motor1.GetPosition(0, originX)
AxMG17Motor2.GetPosition(0, originY)
Dim locations = Enumerable.Range(0, rows - 1).
    Select(Function(r) If(r Mod 2 = 0, Enumerable.Range(0, cols - 1).Select(Function(c) New PointF(r, c)),
                                       Enumerable.Range(cols - 1, 0).Select(Function(c) New PointF(r, c)))).
    SelectMany(Function(p) p)
For Each location In locations
    Dim absoluteX = location.X * jogSizeX + originX
    Dim absoluteY = location.Y * jogSizeY + originY
    AxMG17Motor1.SetAbsMovePos(0, absoluteX)
    AxMG17Motor2.SetAbsMovePos(0, absoluteY)
    Await Task.WhenAll({Task.Run(Sub() AxMG17Motor1.MoveAbsolute(0, True)),
                        Task.Run(Sub() AxMG17Motor2.MoveAbsolute(0, True))})
    Console.WriteLine($"Moved to absolute location: ({absoluteX}, {absoluteY}), relative index: ({location.X}, {location.Y})")
Next
```